# Google+ Follow Button in Email Newsletter

Tags: javascript, email, google-plus, newsletter, google-plus-one

I'm wondering if there is a work-around the Javascript in order to embed a Google+ Follow button (different from Share, different from +1) in an email newsletter. The +Share and +1 have already been solved and/or discussed at length on StackOverflow. I'm primarily just interested in hacking the +Follow!

What I'm looking to accomplish is to reduce the attrition from email to +Page in order to gain a +Follow -- by allowing recipients to simply Follow within the email itself, I hope to improve the conversion from recipient to Google+ Follower.

The Google developers page on the +Follow button is here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for a user to follow a Google+ page in an email client. The best you can do is say "Follow us on Google+" (or the equivalent) and link to the G+ page.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about something similar here: 
http://blog.dmbcllc.com/addthis-from-e-mail/

Basically what you need to do is put the javascript on a web page and link to that web page.  The article uses AddThis.com.  You could either use AddThis and link to everything OR you could adapt the principles in the article for Google+.